# Erratic Lock Screen Behavior - Win 7

Tags: windows-7

If I go to lock my computer and then sign back on, anything I hover my mouse over gets opened. It's like my mouse is being click spammed, or `enter` is being hit frequently. When I hover over the start menu for example it gets opened and closed repeatedly.

This occurs on Windows 7 and I do use a program called "Tweaks Windows Logon Changer" that changes the background of the lock screen. However, even when I stopped using this the problem still occured.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply hovering over an icon and pressing enter shouldn't open it.  It needs to be clicked first before pressing enter will open it.  So... at least that eliminates that possibility?  If you really want to be sure it's not this, unplug the keyboard and try again.

Comment: Sounds like a stuck key or stuck mouse button. I suggest a good clean with a compressed air can, or similar.